# Injecting HttpservletRequest into spring aop

Tags: java, spring, aop, jersey-2.0

I have a restful web service (using spring-jersey, spring 4.1.4, jersey 2.14) ,

```
@POST
@Path("myPath")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.TEXT_HTML })
@CustomAnnotation
public Response myMethod(@Context HttpServletRequest request){

}
```

and I have a spring AOP Advice

```
@Aspect
public class MyAdvice {

@Before(" @annotation(CustomAnnotation)")
public void checkSomething(JoinPoint jp) throws AppException {

    for (Object o : jp.getArgs()) {
        if(o instanceof HttpServletRequest){
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

my question is instead of passing HttpServletRequest as method parameter, can I get access to HttpServletRequest from  inside of my AOP somehow?

i've tried

```
HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
```

inside checkSomething method, and it throws an exception

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.JaxrsRequestAttributes cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: you can not cast org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.JaxrsRequestAttributes to org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes. Because JaxrsRequestAttributes can not find ServletRequestAttributes in his parent hierarchy. org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributes is the parent class of both.